# flutter driver chromedriver couldn't detect chrome

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test, flutterdriver, flutter-integration-test

chromedriver couldn't open the chrome
`dart-debug-extension` was installed but not detected
versions are the same 99

how should i fix this?
for more information
i would insert flutter doctor -v output below

### flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.556], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.10.4 at E:\flutter_windows_2.5.2-stable\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c860cba910 (9 days ago), 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at E:\SDK
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = E:\SDK
    • Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 100.0.4896.60
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 99.0.1150.55

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case it solved just by using edge
and install `dart-debug-extension` on it

```
flutter drive -d edge
```